# How to force a translation to go through an exact point?

Tags: unity, c#, transformation

I have a camera object with a script that will whether translate it with a set speed, or stop it. I also have 7 "checkpoints", where there are 7 different quads, who will stop the camera whenever the camera reaches them.

The problem here is that in my code :

```
void Update() {

if (scoreholder.CheckScore()<scoretimer) {
//if the current score is less than set X score

        if (killcam.transform.position.y == quadholder.y) {
//and if the camera's position equals the position of the generic quad *PROBLEM HERE*

            killcam.GetComponent<cameraUp> ().SetCam (true); //stop the cam

            while (scoreholder.CheckScore () < scoretimer) { // do stuff

                offset = mr.material.mainTextureOffset;
                offset.y += offsetSpeed * 0.1f;
                mr.material.mainTextureOffset = offset;

                break;
            }
        }

    } 

else { //once the score is not less than the desired X score, move the cam
        killcam.GetComponent<cameraUp> ().SetCam (false);
    }

}
```

So my problem here is that this line of code `if (killcam.transform.position.y == quadholder.y)` never happens, the translation skips some values, and the camera doesn't hit the exact quad spot. I tried to use `>` instead of `==`, but I ran into another problem, is that after the 3rd quad, since my camera speed increases in time, the code apparently doesn't get processed fast enough, and my camera goes beyond the 4th,5th,6th, and 7th quad without stopping.

I have already tried `Vector3.Lerp`, and it gives me almost the same result, if I lerp between the beginning and the end of the track, I have to do it with an extremely small fraction, and I can't have my camera move at that speed.

Comment: lerp between the checkpoints over a time that is proportionate tot he distance between the checkpoints

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Vector3.MoveTowards()` will suit your use case perfectly.

Here is the sample from the documentation:

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;

public class ExampleClass : MonoBehaviour {
    public Transform target;
    public float speed;
    void Update() {
        float step = speed * Time.deltaTime;
        transform.position = Vector3.MoveTowards(transform.position, target.position, step);
    }
}
```

Comment: It all works now :) Couldn't have found a better way, thanks a lot.